# Githubのスターはどういう時に送るか

Tags: github

Githubのスターはどういう時に送るものでしょうか。
イケてると思ったプログラムに送るのが普通の使い方かなと思うのですが、以下のような場合に送るのもありですか。
海外も含めて、プログラマ界隈の常識を教えてください、

・OSSを使う時に、使わせていただきますと感謝の気持ちを込めて送る。
・自分の作ったOSSが使われているプロジェクトに、使ってくれてありがとうの意味で送る。
・初心者のソースで、良いソースではないけど、頑張れと応援したくて送る。
・仲良くしたいフォロワーや友達のプログラムに、とりあえず送る。

Comment: 書かれているどのような場合に送っても問題ないですね。要するにSNSの「いいね」と同じようなもので、スターがつくと作者の励みになるので、感謝でも「頑張ってください」でももっと気軽な気持ちでも何か良いと思えば好きなときに付ければいいです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitHub Help の [star に関する記事](https://help.github.com/en/articles/saving-repositories-with-stars)には以下のように書かれています。

> Starring makes it easy to find a repository or topic again later. You can see all the repositories and topics you have starred by going to your stars page.
>
> You can star repositories and topics to discover similar projects on GitHub. When you star repositories or topics, GitHub may recommend related content in the discovery view of your news feed. For more information, see "Finding open source projects on GitHub."
>
> Starring a repository also shows appreciation to the repository maintainer for their work. Many of GitHub's repository rankings depend on the number of stars a repository has. In addition, Explore shows popular repositories based on the number of stars they have.

要約すると：

- 「スターはリポジトリを覚えておくための機能です」
- 「スターすることで GitHub からのオススメを調整できます」
- 「スターをつけることでそのリポジトリのメンテナへの感謝を示すことにもなります」

これより詳しい決まりは、ルールというより個人の信条と言った方が正確かと思います。質問文に挙げられているものはおおかた OK かと思いますが、「良いリポジトリなわけじゃないのにスターするのはおかしくない？」みたいなことを言う方はいます。ですがまあヘルプにしたがう限りスターはリポジトリを覚えておくための機能なので、気にしすぎなくて良いです。

もちろん善悪は問わず傾向としては、無差別にスターを押すとか明らかに悪いリポジトリにスターを押すとかは避けられていそうです。どの程度まで許容できるかは個人の信条でしょう。

Answer (score 2):

nekketsuuu さんの回答でも既に詳しく書かれていますが、私なりの解釈も記してみます。

GitHubでのStarは対象のリポジトリを覚えておくための「ブックマーク/しおり」の側面が強いと思います。
自分がStarを付けたリポジトリを一覧表示して、最近更新のあった順に並べ替えて表示したりもできます。

また、その他のシステム等でも似たような仕組みとして☆が使われています。

- 一部のブラウザ(Firefoxなど)では「ブックマークへの追加」を☆アイコンで表しています。
- ここスタック・オーバーフローでも気になった質問の☆をクリックしてブックマークする機能があります。(これとは別に質問への"評価"は投票機能を使って行うことができます)

たくさん☆が付くという事は「注目に値する ≒ 高評価を得ている」と考えることができるでしょう。